# Two balls are drawn at random from an urn containing six white and ten red balls

Tags: probability

What is the probability that both balls are white?
What is the probability that both balls are red?

How would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution, it is assumed that no balls are replaced in between draws.

During the first draw, the probability of getting a red ball is $\frac{10}{16} = \frac{5}{8}$. For the second draw, there are $9$ red balls left out of $15$ left in the urn, so the probability of getting a second red ball is $\frac{9}{15} = \frac{3}{5}$. Thus, the probability of getting $2$ red balls is $\frac{5}{8}\frac{3}{5} = \boxed{\frac{3}{8}}$.

We use a similar argument for the probability of getting $2$ white balls. The probability of getting a white ball on the first draw is $\frac{3}{8}$, and the probability of getting a second white ball is $\frac{1}{3}$. Thus, the probability of getting $2$ white balls is $\frac{3}{8}\frac{1}{3} = \boxed{\frac{1}{8}}$

Comment: Please correct the numbers. There are six white and ten red balls.